# plot not showing legend when used in Miktex

Tags: miktex, epstopdf, wolfram-mathematica

A have density plot in Mathematica
as

```
  ShowLegend[
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> False, 
PlotPoints -> 30], {ColorData["LakeColors"][1 - #1] &, 10, " 1", 
"-1", LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}}]
```

and corresponding plot is
[image]

When I save this plot as .eps and want to use in Miktex as

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pra,preprint]{revtex4}

\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{ttc.eps}}
\end{document}
```

Then after generating .pdf I get the following kind of plot
[image]

As it is clear from figure, there is missing legend "1".
I have no idea, what is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: Are you able to provide the eps file?

Comment: Did you try making a PDF file directly with the `epstopdf` command line tool?  Do you get the same missing "1"?

Comment: You also can try the excellent `epspdf` utility, which has a Windows graphical interface and an installer, available from [CTAN](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/epspdf-setup/)

Comment: using CTAN helped, but why in Miktex it is giving such kind of result

Comment: @Thruston I dont use command line tool? can you please tell the details

Comment: epstopdf is also on CTAN as a package [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf).  There's a command line interface to the same tools that are called "on the fly" by  `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in LaTeX.  It's hard to tell why your eps file is not being converted correctly without actually looking at it.

Comment: @Peter could not upolad .eps file here

Comment: @Thruston how do I provide .eps file through this platform?

Comment: You can't, you have to upload it to Dropbox or some other file sharing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your plot as a pdf file in mathematica; for example, "ttc.pdf". And then include it into your tex file

```
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{ttc.pdf}
```